# Fixing last of several footers in a certain place, even if preceding footers are suppressed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have to print a report on a pre-printed form. I have 5 footer bands, i.e. page footer A to page footer E. I am printing values in each footer from the sub-report. I am suppressing a footer if the value from the sub-report is zero.

When one or two sections become suppressed, the remaining sections move upwards, which is fine; but the last footer has to be fixed (i.e. it should not move upward).

Comment: I have just tried this with 5 page footers, and footers A-D suppressed and footer E is still on the bottom as it should be. Are you sure they are page footers and not group footers?

Comment: I don't have Crystal in front of me, but I remember having problems with subreport report footers.  In the main report, subreport report footers did not display at the bottom of the page, so I'd move that information out to the main report.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click section in question > Format Section > Print at bottom of page (checkbox) ?